# Predictive distribution with Monte Carlo

Tags: r, prediction, montecarlo, uncertainty

I want to obtain a distribution over each prediction point i.e. for each value of dependent variable y. In the dependent variable y, I have 199 observations and for each observation, I want a distribution.So my output should be a matrix of 199*100. How can I obtain that? I tried the Monte Carlo simulation for T=100.But every time, its a vector of 199 instead of matrix 199*100.[R-Code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJknW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
mc_pred <- matrix(nrow = 199, ncol = 100)

for (i in 1:100) {
    mc_pred[, i] <- predict(model, x_test)
}
```